# Android : How iterate through views of a expandableList

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a expandableList, in child element I have added some EditText, checkbox and spinner. These are created and shown correctly. Additional EditText and Spinner are shown once Checkbox is checked, Then user can add text and select value from spinner.  I want to retrieve values of these additional view(edittext, Spinner, CheckBox) for each of child element. On save click I want to iterate through all elements and retrieve values in these editText, Spinner and checkBox. Currently I am using below code, But after clicking on save, It always returns values associated with last child element. Please let me know if more info is required regarding this question.
[ExpandableList ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMZkz.png)

MainActivity-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

Button save;
Button cancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
// get the listview
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

// preparing list data
prepareListData();

listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

// setting list adapter
expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

expListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Save clicked");
        for(int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount();i++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); k++) {

                String temp = listAdapter.recollect(i,k);
                System.out.println("For i="+i+" and k="+k+" string value is="+temp);
            }
        }
    }
});



}



/*
* Preparing the list data
*/
private void prepareListData() {
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
// Adding child data
listDataHeader.add("Nokia");
listDataHeader.add("Apple");
listDataHeader.add("Samsung");

// Adding child data
List<String> nokia = new ArrayList<String>();
nokia.add("Nokia1");
nokia.add("Nokia2");


List<String> apple = new ArrayList<String>();
apple.add("Apple1");
apple.add("Apple2");


List<String> samsung = new ArrayList<String>();
samsung.add("Samsung1");
samsung.add("Samsung2");

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), nokia); // Header, Child data
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), apple);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), samsung);
}
}
```

MainLayout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="dhritiapps.temp.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/lin"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/can"
android:text="Cancel"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/save"
android:text="Save"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ExpandableListView
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:id="@+id/lvExp"
android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter-

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
// private final HashMap<String, String, String> mCheckedItems;
String cat, item, quty, units, notes;
EditText qty;
EditText note;
Spinner unit;
ArrayList <String> ss=new ArrayList<>();

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
this._context = context;
this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
this._listDataChild = listChildData;

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
.get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}

TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

final LinearLayout mm = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.entries);
qty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
note = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note);
unit = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);

final int grp = groupPosition;

cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

if (cb.isChecked()) {
mm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
mm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
System.out.println(ss);
}
});

txtListChild.setText(childText);

return convertView;
}

public String recollect(int grp, int ch) {
cat = getGroup(grp).toString();
item = getChild(grp, ch).toString();
quty = qty.getText().toString();
units = unit.getSelectedItem().toString();
notes = note.getText().toString();

System.out.println("cat="+cat+"; item="+item+"; qty="+quty+"; unit="+units+"; note="+notes);
return cat+";"+item+";"+quty+";"+units+";"+notes+"_";
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
}
TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return true;
}


}
```

list_Group.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#000000">    

<TextView
android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:textSize="17dp"
android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ef8d8d">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="17dip"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:textColor="#ff0000"
android:layout_weight="5"/>
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cb"
android:checked="false"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:id="@+id/entries"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
<EditText
android:id="@+id/qty"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:hint="Qunatity"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#12f212"
android:layout_margin="3dp"
android:textColor="#700a55"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:maxLength="8"
android:textSize="12dip"/>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/unit"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:entries="@array/units"
android:background="#12f212"
android:layout_margin="3dp"
android:textColor="#700a55"
/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:hint="Note"
android:layout_weight="4"
android:background="#12f212"
android:layout_margin="3dp"
android:textColor="#700a55"
android:textSize="12dip"
android:maxLength="50"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

After clicking save, this is what I am getting-

```
System.out: For i=0 and k=0 string value is=Nokia;Nokia1;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
System.out: For i=0 and k=1 string value is=Nokia;Nokia2;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
System.out: For i=1 and k=0 string value is=Apple;Apple1;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
System.out: For i=1 and k=1 string value is=Apple;Apple2;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
System.out: For i=2 and k=0 string value is=Samsung;Samsung1;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
System.out: For i=2 and k=1 string value is=Samsung;Samsung2;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
```

Though it should have been like this-

```
System.out: For i=0 and k=0 string value is=Nokia;Nokia1;123;A;Note for Note for Nokia1
System.out: For i=0 and k=1 string value is=Nokia;Nokia2;;;
System.out: For i=1 and k=0 string value is=Apple;Apple1;;;
System.out: For i=1 and k=1 string value is=Apple;Apple2;;;
System.out: For i=2 and k=0 string value is=Samsung;Samsung1;;;
System.out: For i=2 and k=1 string value is=Samsung;Samsung2;2;C;Note for Samsung2_
```

Comment: Share @array/units or no matter what it is?

Comment: Can't get your view as you share

Comment: array units have only 3 values as A, B C. <string-array name="units">
        <item></item>
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
    </string-array>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new Class `CustomChilds`

```
package stack.buy.com.stackdemos;

 /**
* Created by Desktop - Ganesh on 10/14/2016.
*/
public class CustomChilds {
 String Quntity;
String Unit;
String Note;
String GroupName;

public String getQuntity() {
    return Quntity;
}

public void setQuntity(String quntity) {
    Quntity = quntity;
}

public String getUnit() {
    return Unit;
}

public void setUnit(String unit) {
    Unit = unit;
}

public String getNote() {
    return Note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    Note = note;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return GroupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    GroupName = groupName;
}

public CustomChilds(String quntity, String unit, String note, String groupName) {
    Quntity = quntity;
    Unit = unit;
    Note = note;
    GroupName = groupName;
}

public CustomChilds() {
}
 }
```

Adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<CustomChilds>> _listDataChild;
// private final HashMap<String, String, String> mCheckedItems;
String cat, item, quty, units, notes;

ArrayList<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<CustomChilds>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}
    @Override
    public CustomChilds getChild( int groupPosition, int childPosititon){
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId ( int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView ( final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        final CustomChilds childText =getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mm = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.entries);
            holder.qty = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.qty1);
            holder.note = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.note);
            holder.unit = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.unit);
            holder.cb = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            holder.txtListChild = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            // view already exists, get the holder instance from the view
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        List<CustomChilds> temp = _listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
        temp.set(childPosition,new  CustomChilds(holder.qty.getText().toString(),holder.unit.getSelectedItem().toString(),holder.note.getText().toString(),childText.GroupName));

        final int grp = groupPosition;

        holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    holder.mm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.mm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                System.out.println(ss);
            }
        });

        holder.txtListChild.setText(childText.getGroupName());

        return row;
    }



@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}



// somewhere else in your class definition
static class ViewHolder {
    EditText qty;
    EditText note;
    Spinner unit;
    LinearLayout mm;
    CheckBox cb;
    TextView txtListChild;
}
 }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<CustomChilds>> listDataChild;

Button save;
Button cancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);


    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);



    expListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

    save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Save clicked");
            for(int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount();i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); k++) {


                    CustomChilds child = listAdapter.getChild(i, k);
                    String unit=child.getUnit();
                    String note=child.getNote();
                    String qut=child.getQuntity();

                    System.out.println("For i="+i+" and k="+k+" string value is="+child.getNote());
                }
            }
        }
    });



}



private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<CustomChilds>>();
    listDataHeader.add("Nokia");
    listDataHeader.add("Apple");
    listDataHeader.add("Samsung");

    List<CustomChilds> nokia = new ArrayList<CustomChilds>();
    nokia.add(new CustomChilds("","","","Nokia1"));
    nokia.add(new CustomChilds("","","","Nokia2"));


    List<CustomChilds> apple = new ArrayList<CustomChilds>();
    apple.add(new CustomChilds("","","","Apple1"));
    apple.add(new CustomChilds("","","","Apple2"));



    List<CustomChilds> samsung = new ArrayList<CustomChilds>();
    samsung.add(new CustomChilds("","","","Samsung1"));
    samsung.add(new CustomChilds("","","","Samsung2"));

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), nokia); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), apple);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), samsung);
}
 }
```

Get Unit, Quantity and Note onClick

```
save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Save clicked");
        for(int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount();i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); k++) {


                CustomChilds child = listAdapter.getChild(i, k);
                String unit=child.getUnit();
                String note=child.getNote();
                String qut=child.getQuntity();

                System.out.println("For i="+i+" and k="+k+" string value is="+child.getNote());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same edit text so it will only give you last values instead add a textchange listener on edit text and in onTextChanged() method add values of that edit text in a list like this:
Also add a tag with position and use tag to retrive the value from list.

myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(myEditText1));

myEditText1.setTag("theFirstEditTextAtPos:"+position);

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

       private View view;
       private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            String text = editable.toString();
            //save the value for the given tag :
            MyResultAdapter.this.textValues.put(view.getTag(), editable.toString());
        }
    }

    //you can implement a method like this one for each EditText with the list position as parameter :
    public String getValueFromFirstEditText(int position){
          //here you need to recreate the id for the first editText
         String result = textValues.get("theFirstEditTextAtPos:"+position);
         if(result ==null)
              result = "default value";

         return result;
    }


}
```